# Generate .rtf files with Monotouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, rtf

I need to generate .rtf files in my Monotouch developed iOS app. I've found libraries working for the .Net platform but not for Monotouch. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some opensource projects to create RTF-documents in that that you could probably use if you recompile them for MonoTouch yourself. This one seems to be built without external dependencies so it should work fine with MonoTouch if just recompiled.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/netrtfwriter/

Comment: It uses System.Drawing which is apparently not supported by MonoTouch. But thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Yes but only to find out the width and height of images it seems. That should be quite easy for you to rewrite using the correct methods in MonoTouch.

Comment: You are right. One more question for this then. How would you find the horizontal resolution for an image in monotouch?

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. You just need to put uiimage.size.height and uiimage.size.width. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Great that it worked out! If my answer ended up solving your problem I would be happy if you could select it as the correct answer as well.